# Given an API with data in json format, how do i present the data in a HTML table?

Tags: php, html, json, postman, dhis-2

So far, I have this PHP cURL code:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://play.dhis2.org/release1/api/25/analytics.json?dimension=dx%3AYtbsuPPo010%3Bl6byfWFUGaP%3Bs46m5MS0hxu&dimension=pe%3ALAST_12_MONTHS&filter=ou%3AImspTQPwCqd&displayProperty=NAME&skipMeta=true",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Basic YWRtaW46ZGlzdHJpY3Q=",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: c7fc6164-194a-24ea-ccea-9f6bdbcd66f5"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

So far I have tried(unsuccessfully) with this:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  $data = json_decode($response, true);

  $immunization = $data["rows"];

  foreach ($immunizations as $immunization) {
    echo '<tr>';

     echo '<td>' . $immunization['name'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $immunization['date'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $immunization['type'] . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
 }
}
```

Someone to help me iterate through the JSON and place the data in rows on my table.

> [API LINK](https://play.dhis2.org/release1/api/25/analytics.json?dimension=dx%3AYtbsuPPo010%3Bl6byfWFUGaP%3Bs46m5MS0hxu&dimension=pe%3ALAST_12_MONTHS&filter=ou%3AImspTQPwCqd&displayProperty=NAME&skipMeta=true)

On postman, use Basic Auth, username: admin, password: district
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have

```
$immunization = $data["rows"];

foreach ($immunizations as $immunization) {
```

You should pluralize the initial `$immunization` as `$immunizations` for it to work. So you get to have

```
$immunizations = $data["rows"];

foreach ($immunizations as $immunization) {
```

Secondly, looking at your returned data, they don't have the `name, date, type` keys. They just have the values there like that. So update your loop to

```
foreach ($immunizations as $immunization) {
   echo '<tr>';

   echo '<td>' . $immunization[0] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $immunization[1] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $immunization[2] . '</td>';

   echo '</tr>';
```

}

Comment: I'm still not getting the data displayed as I want, instead, I have ' . $immunization[0] . ', ' . $immunization[1] . ' and ' . $immunization[2] . ' filling up one row.

Comment: Apparently it was a cURL installation on xampp error. Your correction helped!  Thank You.